# Detection of textarea value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, onchange

How can I detect, that value in my textareaId has changed when the change was caused by javascript?

eg.

```
$("#buttonID").on("click, function(){
        $("#textareaID").val("lorem ipsum");
});

$("#textareaID").change(function(){
      //not working 
}); 

$("#textareaID").bind('input propertychange', function(){
  //not working 
});
```

Comment: you can use `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` event instead

Comment: @Rudra  — "when the change was caused by javascript"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the value of an input programmatically no event is raised by default. If you need this behaviour you need to fire the event yourself, eg:

```
$('#foo').val('bar').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Or simply `$('#foo').val('bar').change()` (without a callback function the `change()` method fires the event).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value from your script doesn't actually fire any of the change or related events, you have to do that yourself at the same time using jQuery's trigger() method:-

```
$("#buttonID").click( function(){
    $("#textareaID").val("Value now added");
    $('#textareaID').trigger('change');   // add this line
});


$("#textareaID").change(function(){
    alert("here");
});
```

Same goes for the input/property change events. You would have to add:

```
    $('#textareaID').trigger('input propertychange');
```

Comment: Yes, the same as Rory said. Thank you too.